# Detect if a web request is the result of an <img src=""> tag

Tags: asp.net, html

If you have `<img src="">` on your page, the image load will result in another web request to the page that was originally loaded.  Is there a way (in ASP.NET) to detect that the web request was the result of being loaded for an `<img>` tag like this?

The only difference I can find is the HTTP_ACCEPT value of `*/*` for `<IMG>` requests, vs. a limited HTTP_ACCEPT value for the actual page request.  I am fearful that will be too restrictive though.

Comment: Why do you want this? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I have found that it's possible for my site to incorrectly render such a tag in some circumstances, and it's leading to additional load where the server reprocesses the web request for the <img> tag.  If the request came from an <img> tag, I want to throw an exception rather than allowing the page to load.

Comment: @Sjoerd: That is a classic way of breaking ASP.NET very badly. It will cause the default page to reload (possibly infinitely).

Comment: Fixing the badly rendered `<img>` tag would seem like a better approach here.

Comment: Yes, I agree... but I want to put a preventative measure in too.

Comment: @Sjoerd I guess if you were doing something like, say, myminicity, where unique hits on your city's URL rack up points, you would (hopefully) want to discourage people from posting broken "images" in every forum they could find.

Answer (score 0):

dont know about built in function, but you can pass some query string parameter from src="..." url, and detect that parameter in the page load event of requested page.

Comment: That would require that every real page load has a query string though, right?